# Adding scalar to indicator function

Tags: optimization

I'm doing some self-study and came across this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04925v1.pdf) where it appears in Section 4 the authors are adding a scalar to the vector $\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}$. The other two functions called $f$ are $\min_{\boldsymbol x} -\frac12 \boldsymbol x^T \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol z_i \boldsymbol z_i^T \Big ) \boldsymbol x + \gamma \|\boldsymbol x\|^2$. And this function $f$ is added to $g$, which is the indicator function $\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}$.

In other word, it's unclear to me how this result is a scalar

$$
\min_{\boldsymbol x} -\frac12 \boldsymbol x^T \Big ( \sum_{i=1}^n \boldsymbol z_i \boldsymbol z_i^T \Big ) \boldsymbol x + \gamma \|\boldsymbol x\|^2 + \boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}
$$

I'm pretty sure I'm the one in error here since they've gone ahead to declare results in the paper. I'm just curious how $g$ could be added to $f$ and still produce a scalar value $f+g$.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The $\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}$ is in the $\min_x$ so that it's a scalar : $1$ if $x\ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Does it mean it just adds a scalar 1 to $f$ in the objective function, if $x \geq 0$?

Comment: Yes, that's it !

Comment: But isn't $\boldsymbol x$ a vector?